# Is there a single "dashboard" screen for Stackoverflow/Stackexchange?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, multiple-accounts

I would like to have a dashboard page for my profile which can list the status / points, and any changes to my questions. It would be easier for me to look on one page rather than traverse all the different stack sites. The "Stackexchange" icon is not really that helpful as I am across so many sites, it warrants a dedicated page.

Do you think this is a good idea ? Or does something like this already exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You mean like this?](https://stackexchange.com/users/933c7158-9a18-4792-90c4-86704f165f62?tab=accounts)

Have you tried going to [the Stack Exchange site](http://www.stackexchange.com), logging in, then clicking your username link near the top?

Comment: Doh! Yes. I didn't know it was there... Now I do thanks...

Comment: I had EXACTLY the same question (the site nicely zapped me over to your existing question.)   However, my reaction was the same -- "ohhh, it's in that place."   I strongly suggest that the stackexchange gang (1) more clearly signpost that function on the central site, and guide all users to it ... and (2) possibly adjust that dashboard page so that the first tab that comes up is in fact the ACCOUNTS tab, which is the one that we are really craving. You can take the "TOP" tab and insert it into a sliver of real estate somewhere on the ACCOUNTS tab - as the TOP tab is not much bulky info.

Comment: Boy, just to repeat... if the central hub page was integrated excellently -- with the activity feed central, the overall "account" matrix located in a very convenient place (even on the same page?), I swear, I would visit stackoverflow just as obsessively as facebook.